# DataField values in Column instead of Row

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have written below code to set the row and datafields of a pivottable which is already present in my sheet.

My issue is that datafields are showing in rows instead of columns. it is like -

wrong

[image]

I want it like -

correct

[image]

```
Sub Create_CR_DT
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

'Remove existing Data fields
For Each pf In pt.DataFields
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
Next pf

'Remove existing Row fields
For Each pf In pt.RowFields
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
Next pf

'Remove existing Column fields
For Each pf In pt.ColumnFields
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
Next pf


'Set VR.NO as 1st row
pt.PivotFields(" VR. NO.").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields(" VR. NO.").Position = 1

'Set DataFields
pt.PivotFields("INCOME TAX").Orientation = xlDataField
pt.PivotFields("CESS").Orientation = xlDataField
pt.PivotFields("I.G.S.T").Orientation = xlDataField
pt.PivotFields("C.G.S.T").Orientation = xlDataField
pt.PivotFields("C.G.S.T BY CASH").Orientation = xlDataField
pt.PivotFields("S.G.S.T").Orientation = xlDataField 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled again in the Morning and after 4-5 attempts I am able to solve it by myself.

Just added below line in the end and it worked.

pt.DataPivotField.Orientation = xlColumnField

Thanks all!!